# How is さすがに (sasugani) used?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I have read so many posts, asked so many times to friends and people on forum but still I don't get how to use さすがに without sounding a weirdo. I know that it doesn't have anything to do with さすが！ and it can be translated as "understandably". However, in some cases it's still wrong. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is さすが when referring to oneself?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/what-is-%e3%81%95%e3%81%99%e3%81%8c-when-referring-to-oneself)

Comment: Perhaps existing answers in the linked post contain examples that are less likely to be used in daily conversations. An answer with more relevant examples is needed (I might write one).

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to begin with `さすがに` and followed by something i.e. an adjective. The sentence might not make sense by itself, since it only tells the effect without any cause.

> **さすがに** 疲{つか}れます・疲れました。
>
> **As expected**, [I] become tired/am tired;
>
> [I] become tired/am tired **for sure**.

For individual sentences, the sentence containing `さすがに` is usually preceded by another sentence that has the cause, or may be used after the first conversation as a reply.

> 家から駅まで 歩いて３０分。**さすがに** 疲れます。
>
> It takes 30 minutes by walking from [my] house to the station. [I] become tired **for sure**.
>
> Q: 初めてのマラソンは どうでしたか？
>
> Q: How was [your] first time doing the marathon?
>
> A: **さすがに** 疲れました。
>
> A: **As expected**, [I] am tired.

For combined sentences, the part containing `さすがに` may be found at the beginning of sentence or somewhere in the middle of sentence.

> **さすがに**　地元{じもと}の有名{ゆうめい}人だけあって、 近所{きんじょ}で 話題{わだい}になる。
>
> **As expected** of being a local celebrity, [the celebrity] becomes the popular topic of conversation in the neighbourhood.
>
> 日{にち}曜日は　休{きゅう}日{じつ}でも、**さすがに**　誰{だれ}もが休{やす}める　訳{わけ}ではない。
>
> Even Sunday is a rest day, **certainly** that does not mean anyone could just take rest.

Based on above sentences, the following patterns can be reused.

- さすがに ○○ます・ました。
- さすがに ○○だけあって、 ○○。
- ○○も、 さすがに ○○ない。

This answer includes only few examples to get started. Note that these examples are limited to `さすがに`, and other forms of `さすが` such as `さすがの` and `さすがは` will *not* be covered here.

> 「さすが」に合う例文{れいぶん}を 全部 書きとめるのは、 **さすがに** 一苦労{ひとくろう}。
>
> [One] is **certainly** to have a hard time for writing down all example sentence that fits well with "さすが".

The last example concludes this answer with pun intended.

Answer (score 4):

（Quoted from Kōjien）

> さすがに
>
> 1.そうは思うものの、やはり。そうではあるが。伊勢物語「—哀れとや思ひけむ」。「—そこまでは言えない」
>   2.すぐれただけあって。評判だけあって。何といってもやはり。後撰和歌集秋「秋風の吹けば—わびしきは」。「—名人だけのことはある」
>  3.他とは違って。他はともかくも。謡曲、羅生門「—羅生門は都の南門ならずや」

Explanation:

Briefly speaking, there are three adverb usages, and could only be subtly differentiated in my opinion…

The first one is like "despite that, …"

The second one usually implies compliments, and as I see it, it's similar with さすが, while this one with に gives me an impression that it is more of a adverb, which is used to qualify verb or adjectives.

The third one sounds pretty much like the second one to me as well, but it seems to be sort of obsolete.

Comment: I have read this kind of explanation but my problem is how to use °sasugani° in a sentence? Everytime I use that, everyone is like °NOOOOOOO. You should use °yappari°°. But, when they use that, °No, this is the correct way, you foooool° but it seems that native speakers decide case by case whether it's correct or not. I really don't have any clue about the correct usage.

Comment: I am a Japanese learner as well, for me, "yappari" differs with "sasugani" in contextual aspect. The sooner contains the implications that  you have firmly(mostly subjectively) known sth would happen to sb, whereas the latter implies that everyone hearing this conversation would agree with you on your judgement. Usually "sasugani" only applies to those who is positively entitled with some position, rank, etc..