# What does this mean ? [Manga] MC's complain about a character,who criticizes other's action reckless but her actions is no different in the past

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english, conversations

Context: MC and his friends are talking with 1 girl (C-san), who just broke out of a castle's siege (alone with no soldiers), then ran to them asking for help

A-san and B-san are members of MC team.

> G1: C-sanと言ったか。県令の書状は本物のようだが……他の兵は？
>
> C-san: 最初から連れてきてないよ。私一人で抜ける方が楽だったからね
>
> A-san: 敵陣を単身突破とは……また、無茶をする
>
> MC: ............. (staring at A-san)
>
> A-san: ご主人様。私の顔に、何か付いていますか？
>
> MC: …いや、別に
>
> **MC's thought: 賊退治をB-sanと二人でしてた愛紗に言われてもなぁ……と思ったけど、さすがに口には出さないでおく。**

I'm not quite clear about what he's meant here, so if anyone can please help me to understand.

(my guess: "So A-san criticize C-san's action was reckless, when she and B-san even with just 2 people - have exterminated an entire bandit huh ..... That's what I had in mind, but as expected I will keep this to myself" ? feel free to correct me)

Comment: Is C-san 愛紗? if so, it's kinda obfuscating, edit it to C-san or reveal all of their name

Comment: If your doubt is about さすがに, I would suggest you make that point clearer in the title as well as in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

～に言われても, literally "even if (this) is said by ～", is a common set phrase used for *tsukkomi*. It roughly means the same thing as the English set phrase "You can talk" or "Look who's talking". It's a little milder version of [お前が言うな](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%8A%E5%89%8D%E3%81%8C%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA). So MC is thinking A was doing something equally reckless.

> 賊退治をB-sanと二人でしてた愛紗に言われてもなぁ……
>
> (literally) Even if this is said by 愛紗, who were exterminating the bandits alone with B, well... [it's not convincing].
>
> → Look who's talking! Wasn't she exterminating the bandits alone with B?

(Note that ～に言われても can also mean "You're talking to a wrong person" or "～ is not in charge of that" due to the [ambiguity of に in passive sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/87144/5010). あなたに言われても typically means "You can talk", whereas わたしに言われても typically means "I'm not in charge of this", "Don't tell that to me", etc.)

Your understanding of the latter half is basically okay, but here 流石に has a nuance of "still" or "nonetheless"; it implies he thought it was not the right time to say something humorous. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82331/5010).